# Convert code from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.0 for Error Handling

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, swift2

Swift 1.2 Code:

```
var error:NSError? = nil

if (fileManager.removeItemAtPath(exportPath as String, error: &error))
{
    //Error - handle if requried
}
```

I am unable to get this code compile to Swift 2.0 when I am using try and catch block.

Swift 2.0 Code

```
do {
    check = try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(exportPath as String)
    if(//some condition)
    {
        // whatever                    
    }
}
catch {
    check = nil
}
```

Comment: Post the code with try..catch. Which code is really not working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the way to go, you don't need the `error` param anymore!

```
do {
    try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(exportPath as String)
} catch {
    // Error - handle if required
}
```

Comment: How can i check that try line in if condition?

Comment: Why you want to check it? You used to be forced to do thinks like that just to manage errors but that is not the way anymore...

Comment: Thnx for your answer.

Comment: If you need the error information change the catch line like so:  

catch let error as NSError{ 
//report error
}